# "aws s3 rm" command taking a long time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a reason why this command just hangs and doesn't produce any output? As far as I can tell I'm using the proper syntax:

```
aws s3 rm s3://myBucket/ --exclude "*" --include "history*" --dryrun
```

Comment: What is the size of your bucket?

Comment: Its fairly large - about 2TB but also only need the root scanned, no subfolders etc

Comment: Well, last time my command to fetch the bucket size took around 30 minutes, and my bucket was only 70gb. So a `rm` commands with filter should take a couple of hours on a big bucket.

Comment: good thing my token only lasts an hour :(

Comment: I think you are good. AWS will not try to authenticate you again while an operation is running.

Comment: This command should technically produce output, since you're not passing the `--quiet` parameter...does it only provide the final output of the list of commands it will use as part of "dryrun"? I personally never used `rm` but commands like `sync` and `mv` show line by line as they process things

Answer (score 2):

This operation in large buckets is not only slow but also will incur costs. What you can do is to create a lifecycle rule applied only to objects with „history“ prefix and let the lifecycle rule to expire, then delete those files automatically. You can follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html to explore the options there. Also this blog post will help: https://link.medium.com/gtEvLQ5YtV